# String str1=new String("abc"); String str2="abc" returning same hashcode

Tags: java, string

I am trying the attached code. I thought the below two references were different but does the attached output shows the same hashcode? I was in the assumption that both are different?
Are they different in anyways?

```
String str1=new String("abc");      
String str3="abc";
```

Below is the code from Eclipse with output

[image: Eclipse output]

Comment: Don't confuse "same hashcode" with "same reference". Objects that are equal (even if not same) _have_ to have the same hashcode.

Comment: So are str1 and str3 are at different memory locations? I mean str1 is inside String pool and str3 inside heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse "same hashcode" with "same reference". For `Object` (and any class that does not override `hashCode`) the hashcode *does* represent something like the memory address,<sup>1)</sup> but in general, objects that are equal (even if not the same) should have the same hashCode.

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
String s3 = new String("abc");

System.out.println(s1.hashCode()); // 96354
System.out.println(s2.hashCode()); // 96354
System.out.println(s3.hashCode()); // 96354
```

That does not mean that they are the same, though. While `s1` and `s2` are the same (pooled) string, i.e. the same object in memory, `new String` will indeed create a different (but equal) object.

```
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
System.out.println(s1 == s3); // false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3)); // true
```

If you want to get a different hash code for different objects, like for `Object.hashCode`,<sup>1)</sup> you can use `System.identityHashcode`.

```
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1)); // 225534817
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2)); // 225534817
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s3)); // 1878246837
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Which *might* be the actual memory address, but this is not part of the "contract" of the method, i.e. more of an implementation detail. In particular, this value stays the same over the lifetime of the object even if its memory location should change (thanks to [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760701/string-str1-new-stringabc-string-str2-abc-returning-same-hashcode/68760851?noredirect=1#comment121520427_68760851) for pointing this out).

Comment: what exactly is hashcode and why is it is calculated?

Comment: @NiketBhagwath You need the hash code e.g. for efficiently storing and retrieving objects in `Set` or `Map` structures; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Comment: The hashcode of `Object` does not represent the memory address. Garbage collectors can move objects around in memory, but identity hashcodes are stable.

Answer (score 0):

The general contract of hashCode is:

1. Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
2. **If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method,
   then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
   produce the same integer result.**
3. It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
   hash tables.

So if str1.equals(str3) is true, str1.hashCode() must be equal to str2.hashCode()

Answer (score 0):

The object *reference* of "str1" and "str3" will **still** be different. However, the *hashcode* will be similar because of the *hashcode* (method) implementation of `String` class. Point to note here is that, object *reference* is different from object *hashcode*. And, it is possible that two objects (with different *reference*) might have similar *hashcode*, based on the implementation of *hashcode* method.

"str1" will be stored inside heap, while "str3" will be stored inside `StringPool` (which itself is part of heap).